# recursive reverse function with starting value of 1

Tags: recursion, f#

The following code works to replace the first element of the array,
but I would like to specify a value of 1 instead of a value of 0 to
delete the first element of the array.

```
let rec replace index value list =
    match index, list with
    | 0, x::xs -> value::xs
    | index, x::xs -> x::replace (index - 1) value xs
    | index, [] -> failwith "index out of range"

let replaceCharArray = replace 0 'd' ['a';'b';'c']
printfn "%A" replaceCharArray
```

I modified my code working code above so that I may do that, but now I
am getting an out of range exception.

```
let rec replace index value list =
    match index, list with
    | 0, x::xs -> value::xs
    | index, x::xs -> x::replace ((index - 1) - 1) value xs
    | index, [] -> failwith "index out of range"

let replaceCharArray = replace 1 'd' ['a';'b';'c']
printfn "%A" replaceCharArray
```

Can someone please help me figure out why I am getting an out of range
exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let rec replace index value list =
    match index, list with
    | 0, _ -> failwith "index out of range"
    | 1, x::xs -> value::xs
    | index, x::xs -> x::replace (index - 1) value xs
    | index, [] -> failwith "index out of range"
```

Comment: Which could be shortened by making the first pattern `| 0, _ | _, []` and removing the last line.